# Accessing Windows Display via WSL X Server

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xserver

I develop my projects within WSL and display visualizations, etc. with VcXsrv X server and `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0`. This is usually fine.

For a new project, I'd like to access the Windows 10 display (not necessarily the X server), e.g., a screenshot function would capture whatever Windows is displaying and not the black root of the X server. Changing `DISPLAY` to something like `:0` or `127.0.0.1:0.0` do not help.

Any search I do here or elsewhere yields results pertaining to the display of WSL-based windows, not Windows-based windows.